# Evaluate double integral with exponential

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

Trying to integrate the following integral.

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy e^{-(x-y)^2}$$.

I've tried pulling out $x$ from the square and setting $s=\frac{y}{x}$ gives me the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty ds \int_{-\infty}^\infty dx -xe^{-x^2(1-s)^2}/2$$

However, it becomes zero when the integral over $x$ is taken and I know that my answer should be nonzero so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This integral does not converge, which can be seen by substituting $z := x-y$.

Comment: Let $u=x-y, v=x$.

Comment: @xpaul how would the integral look then explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Let  $u=x-y$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty dy e^{-(x-y)^2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty du e^{-u^2}=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx \sqrt\pi=\infty. $$

Comment: Isn't there a way to renormalize if one knows that the RHS also contains and infinity?